# Swing / AWT filechooser validation graphics drawing

Tags: java, swing, validation, awt, jtextarea

I'm making a drawing program which reads commands from a text file, when file is selected the program should validate the commands for correct entry parameters. the text file opened in the program includes;

```
Move 100 100 // (move pen to X Y)
MIVE 100 50 // (Invalid comamnd spelt incorrectly)
move x y // (invalid command not an integer)
Line 20 100 // (draw a line at X Y)
```

The problem that I am having is that upon opening the text file into the program, it is importing the text file but it is not validating it into the `JTextArea` and drawing the line at selected X / Y co-ordinates. Could anybody point me in the right direction?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class Instructionpanel extends JPanel {

JTextArea instructions;

// Move line text clear
public Instructionpanel(GraphicsPanel graphicspanel) {

    instructions = new JTextArea(
            "This is where the instructions will displayed", 10, 50); // Rows
                                                                        // *
                                                                        // columns
    instructions.setLineWrap(true);
    instructions.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    instructions.setEditable(true);
    JScrollPane areaScrollPane = new JScrollPane(instructions);
    areaScrollPane
            .setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    add(areaScrollPane);
    // add(instructions);
}

public void processFile(File file) {
    Scanner scan = null;
    try {
        scan = new Scanner(file);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException el) {
        el.printStackTrace();
    }

    String allInstructions = "";

    String allInstructions1 = "";
    String instruction = "";
    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        instruction = scan.nextLine() + "\n";
        // check or validate the instruction

        allInstructions1 += validateInstruction(instruction);

    }

    instructions.setText(allInstructions1);

}

public String validateInstruction(String orig) {
    String returnString = orig;

    // Do all the checking
    // Convert string to an array
    String command = "";
    String[] instructionArray = orig.split("  ");

    int x, y = 0;

    switch(instructionArray[0])
        {
    case "MOVE":
        // Check there three parameters
        doMove( instructionArray );            {
            // And they are integers
            instructions = new JTextArea(" Incorrect parameter type i.e 100");
            instructions = new JTextArea(":incorrect number of parameters i.e Line 100 200");
            try {

                GraphicsPanel.setPos (Integer.parseInt(instructionArray[1]),Integer.parseInt(instructionArray[2]));

            } 

            catch (NumberFormatException e) 
            {
                instructions = new JTextArea(" only numbers are allowed ");
            }
        }
        break;

            case "LINE":
                doLine ( instructionArray );
        // Check there three parameters
        if (instructionArray.length != 3) {
            // And they are integers
            instructions = new JTextArea(" Incorrect parameter type i.e 100");
            instructions = new JTextArea(":incorrect number of parameters i.e Line 100 200");
            try {
                GraphicsPanel.drawLine (Integer.parseInt(instructionArray[1]),Integer.parseInt(instructionArray[2]));
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                instructions = new JTextArea(" only numbers are allowed ");
            }break;

            }}
    return orig;}

private void doLine(String[] instructionArray) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
private void doMove(String[] instructionArray) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
}
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [mcve]. To make it an MCVE, it needs to be Complete (in one single copy/paste) so it will need to have the data hard coded in the source code as a `String` and include a main method to put it on-screen. BTW - I note that except for the first question you asked, you have received no answers. Further, you have been advised on at least one previous occasion to post an SSCCE (which is the equivalent of an MCVE) & have so far failed to grasp the advantage of doing so. You might want to reflect on those points, if you wish to get successful solutions on SO.

Comment: Yeah, so i've acknowledged however, I'm not the most familiar user when it comes to java, starting from scratch is not an option my assignment is due in a day.

Comment: *"..my assignment is due in a day"* Then you should have started sooner and/or used better time management. And in future, please don't mistake your problems, for ours. People who help for free generally prefer to help others with good time management skills, at least time enough to follow their advice.

Answer (score 0):

From a quick look I can say that your `String[] instructionArray` probably created with only one element since the `orig.split("  ")` has double space as a delimiter, therefore `instructionArray[0]` contains the whole line since your tokens are spaced with only one space. Therefore none of your cases in `validateInstruction(String orig)` are matched.

For now you can probably get away with replacing the double space to single space in the `orig.split("  ")` call.

That being said I cant guaranty this will solve all the potential issues that might occur after the change.